# Unable to pull images from Artifact Registry when deploying to Cloud Run

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, google-artifact-registry, google-devtools-cloudbuild

**Introduction**

I am using Cloud Build for learning how to build Docker images, storing them in Artifact Registry and then deploying the final product to Cloud Run. Please see the `cloudbuild.yaml` below:

```
steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '.', '-t', '[REGION]-docker.pkg.dev[projectId]/[repository]/[image]:latest']

  # Push to Artifact Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', '[REGION]-docker.pkg.dev[projectId]/[repository]/[image]:latest']

  # List Docker images (for debugging)
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['images']

  # Log in to Artifact Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['login', '[REGION]-docker.pkg.dev[projectId]/[repository]/[image]:latest']

  # Deploy to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcloud'
    args:
      - 'run'
      - 'deploy'
      - 'REPLACE_WITH_SERVICE_NAME'
      - '--image'
      - '[REGION]-docker.pkg.dev[projectId]/[repository]/[image]:latest'
      - '--region'
      - 'REPLACE_WITH_REGION'
      - '--platform'
      - 'managed'
      - '--allow-unauthenticated'
```

All the steps are marked as successful in Cloud Build, but when it reaches the deployment to Cloud Run step it shows this error message:

`Error response from daemon: pull access denied for gcloud, repository does not exist or may require docker login:denied:requested access to the resource is denied`

I have been reading through the documentation and I made sure that the following requirements are met:

1. I followed this Artifact Registry [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/pushing-and-pulling#pulling) for setting this up
2. The repository and image exist in Artifact Registry
3. Cloud Build service account has the necessary permissions to manage Artifact Registry resources:

   - roles/artifactregistry.reader
   - roles/artifactregistry.writer

**Questions:**

- Am I missing any step in my cloudbuild.yaml?
- Why I can push images to Artifact Registry, but not pull them for deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is attributable to incorrect build configuration (`cloudbuild.yaml`)

In the build configuration you have a step with the name "gcloud".  The `Name` of the step is not an arbitrary string, but needs to refer to the existing `docker` image. If the image is not prefixed with the domain it is being looked at in `docker hub`.

Check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/cloud-builders#publicly_available_images) on using `cloud build` to understand what the name parameter of the step is.

And also check [this document](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-cloud-run#continuous_deployment) for sample `cloud run` deployment from `cloud build`

```
  steps:
  # Build the container image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA', '.']
  # Push the container image to Container Registry
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA']
  # Deploy container image to Cloud Run
  - name: 'gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk'
    entrypoint: gcloud
    args:
    - 'run'
    - 'deploy'
    - 'SERVICE-NAME'
    - '--image'
    - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
    - '--region'
    - 'REGION'
  images:
  - 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/SERVICE-NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
```